# Unicode input by character name

Tags: keyboard, unicode, unicode-entry

I greatly dislike inputing unicode symbols by their code numbers. Usually, the way I input these characters is by using Ctrl+Shift+U then typing the code and pressing enter. For example, λ is 'u03BB', I, recently, discovered that I can obtain it by typing 'ulambda', which is amazing. Unfortunately, this doesn't give what I expect many times. For example 'upi' gives  and not π. I was not able to find a table of symbols by their names, so I discover them by trial and error.

I greatly prefer typing the symbol name over its code,

Is there such a table giving the name to charater mapping when using Ctrl+Shift+U available?

Is it possible to make Ctrl+Shift+U give me π when I type 'upi'?